# How do I determine if I have execute permissions on a DB programatically?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a Windows Service that requires execute permissions on a SQL Server 2005 DB. On start up I check to see if I can connect to the DB and stop the service if I can't. I also want to do a check to see if I can execute a stored procedure using that connection. Is there a way to do that without actually attempting to execute a sproc and looking at the exception if one occurs?

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484145/ms-sql-server-check-to-see-if-a-user-can-execute-a-stored-procedure).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL 2005 and on you can check any permission with [`HAS_PERM_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx):

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('sp_foo', 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE');
```

Answer (score 3):

you could run a query like this:

```
SELECT
    o.NAME,COALESCE(p.state_desc,'?permission_command?')+' '+COALESCE(p.permission_name,'?permission_name?')+' ON ['+SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)+'].['+COALESCE(o.Name,'?object_name?')+'] TO ['+COALESCE(dp.Name,'?principal_name?')+']' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS GrantCommand
    FROM sys.all_objects                          o
        INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions       p ON o.OBJECT_ID=p.major_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals  dp ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
    where p.state_desc='GRANT' AND p.permission_name='EXECUTE'
        AND o.NAME='YourProcedureName'
        AND dp.Name='YourSecurityName'
```

...and remove the fancy formatting of the grant command, it is there only for reference

these are nice too...

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('YourTable', 'OBJECT') 
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('YourProcedure', 'OBJECT') 
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER')
```

To see what permissions someone else has you can do this:

```
EXECUTE AS user = 'loginToTest'
GO
PRINT 'SELECT permissions on tables:'
SELECT
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(    QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id))+'.' + QUOTENAME(name)
                          ,'OBJECT','SELECT'
                     ) AS have_select
        , * 
    FROM sys.tables;

PRINT 'EXECUTE permissions on stored procedures:'
SELECT
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(    QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
        ,'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') AS have_execute
        , * 
    FROM sys.procedures;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this answer shows how you can check rights in **T-SQL**, the second part gives an example how to use this in the **Entity Framework** (note that there are differences between the EF versions - the example given is EF 4, but can be changed easily to a newer version):

---

**First part (SQL):**

I am using the following **T-SQL** script to check permissions. It first checks if you have any rights, then it checks execute permissions for the SPs, finally select permissions for the tables. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx) link to get more information.

```sql
-- 1. Do I have any permissions?
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'ANY') DoIHaveAnyRights;

-- 2. create list of schemas
declare @SchemaList table (schema_id int, name nvarchar(max));

PRINT 'Schemas regarded:'

insert into @SchemaList
select distinct schema_id, name FROM sys.schemas
where name in ('dbo') -- enter the schemas you like to check comma-separated

SELECT s.name, s.schema_id FROM sys.schemas s
join @SchemaList sl on s.schema_id=sl.schema_id

-- 3. check execute permissions
PRINT 'EXECUTE permissions on stored procedures:'
SELECT 
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
        ,'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') AS [have execute]
        ,'['+s.name +'].['+ t.name+']' as [object]
        --, * 
    FROM sys.procedures t
    join @SchemaList s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id
order by s.name, t.name;

-- 4. check select permissions
PRINT 'SELECT permissions on tables:'
SELECT 
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id))+'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
        ,'OBJECT','SELECT') AS [have select]
        ,'['+s.name +'].['+ t.name+']' as [object]
        --, * 
    FROM sys.tables t
    join @SchemaList s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id
order by s.name, t.name;
```

With the **Northwind database** for example, this gives you the following result:

[image: Query_results]

**Note** that you can configure the schemas regarded in step 2. If you don't need a limited set of schemas checked, you can just comment out the `where` clause in the `insert into @SchemaList` statement to get all schemas.

---

**Second part (Entity Framework):**

In this section, I'd like to show you, how you can get the results into Entity Framework.
Let's suppose you want to check if you have any rights **before** using any of the tables in your LINQ queries. Take a look at this example (for simplicity, I've done it in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), please add `System.Data.Entity.dll` and its namespaces via F4 before you run it):

```csharp
void Main()
{
    var dc=this;
    var sql="SELECT TOP 1 "
              + "HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'ANY') DoIHaveAnyRights;";
    var result=dc.ExecuteStoreQuery<Rights>(sql);
    if (result1.DoIHaveAnyRights==1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK"); // ok
    }
    else
    {
        // no rights: Show error etc.
        Console.WriteLine("No rights"); // ok
    }
}

public class Rights
{
    public Int32 DoIHaveAnyRights { get; set; }
}
```

Likewise you can use the query from the first part of my answer, e.g.:

```csharp
var sql="select top 1 case when cnt.NoRightsCount=0 then 1 else 0 end "
+"as DoIHaveAnyRights "
+"from (SELECT count(1) NoRightsCount FROM sys.procedures t "
+"where HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME("
+"QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)"
+",'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE')<>1) cnt";
```

This query will check if there are any stored procedures in your database for which you have no rights to execute - in this case the return value would be `result1.DoIHaveAnyRights!=1`.

I think you get the idea, play around with the possibilities: Keep in mind that EF requires access to all the database tables, stored procedures etc. you're mapping to - you could use the code above to check before you access them. Unfortunately, there is currently no easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have rights to access the DataDictionary for your database and run a query against it to determine which permissions the account you log in with has. This would vary from database to database.