# SQL SERVER stored procedure problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure using SQL Server Management studio.

I am able to create it but if I tryto right click on the stored procedure and execute it, I am getting `permission denied error# 229`.

I have administrator rights. How can I execute this procedure.

Comment: Can you execute it from the script window (`exec sp_YourProcedure`)? [This question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002773/permissions-issue-in-ssms-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-exten) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are really connecting as **sa** this should not happen, if you are not, could be that your user does not really have all the rights.

It is also difficult to understand the problem without seeing the body of the stored in case you are doing anything special in there.

at this link anyway: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic463688-146-1.aspx somebody was discussing the same error and there are some SQL commands scrolling down the page where some people claim to have fixed the issue.

Comment: A little explanation from OP what from this answer exactly solved his problem wouldn't hurt...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have sufficient permissions?
[Error 229 means that you don't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937592%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Your user needs at least `EXECUTE` permissions for the stored procedure:
[Stored Procedure and Permissions - Is EXECUTE enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815411/stored-procedure-and-permissions-is-execute-enough)

Here's how you can check if you have the permission:
[MS SQL Server: Check to see if a user can execute a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484145/ms-sql-server-check-to-see-if-a-user-can-execute-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you didn't add your user to any of the deny roles, like `db_denydatareader`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add execute privillages to your SQL Login:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SPNAME TO UserName;
GO
```